# Bivariate negative binomial distribution for 2d count data

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

**Bivariate negative binomial distribution**

The probability mass function (PMF) of a *bivariate* negative binomial distribution ($\mathsf{BNBin}$) is given by [1]:

$$P(X=x, Y=y) = \frac{(a + x + y - 1)!}{(a-1)! x! y!} p_0^a p_1^x p_2^y $$

where $a, p_0, p_1, p_2 > 0$ and $p_0 + p_1 + p_2 = 1$. It can be shown that the marginal $P(X)$ of this distribution follows a negative binomial ($\mathsf{NBin}$) with parameters $r=a$ and $p=\frac{p_1}{1 - p_2}$ (and similarly $r=a$ and $p=\frac{p_2}{1 - p_1}$ for $P(Y)$).

---

**Small motivating example**

Consider the following 2d count dataset:

| $X$ | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $Y$ | 7 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The marginal distributions are both $\mathsf{NBin}$:
[image]

However, the joint distribution $P(X, Y)$ cannot effectively be modeled as a  $\mathsf{BNBin}$. This is because the covariance of $\mathsf{BNBin}$, $\text{Cov}(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}[XY] - \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{ap_1p_2}{p_0}$, is always positive, but the variables $X$ and $Y$ are negatively correlated (the sample covariance is approximately -0.77).

---

**Questions**

- Under what conditions is the $\mathsf{BNBin}$ distribution suitable for 2d count data?
- Is there any other 2d distribution for count data that generalises $\mathsf{BNBin}$? If not, how could $\mathsf{BNBin}$ be extended to deal with these failure cases? (e.g. negative correlation between both variables)

Any comment or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

---

References:

[1] Dunn 1967, Characterization of the Bivariate Negative Binomial Distribution ([pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/84121314.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried modelling your data with [copulas?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory))
In this case you can choose your margins independently from your dependence structure, meaning that you can choose your margins as negative binomial, but you can choose the dependence between them in such a way that you have (for example) a negative association between the variables.
To answer your questions:

- Your joint distribution (which is one possible bivariate distribution with negative binomial margins) is appropriate if there is reason to believe that your data are in line with the implied constraints on the parameters. Even if the margins are negative binomial, why should their parameters be related by $p=p_1/(1-p_2)$ for $X$ and $p=p_2/(1-p_1)$ for $Y$? Why should the correlation only be positive?
- There is an infinite number of possible distributions with negative binomial margins. Some will have a positive correlation (like the one you cite), others will not. Using copulas you can avoid linking the marginal parameters with the parameters that describe the dependence between the variables.

Comment: Thank you! I never heard about copulas, it seems like a promising direction. What I like about Dunn's $\mathsf{BNBin}$ is that the analytical formula for the joint PMF is available (this is something desirable for the tasks that I am after, e.g. computing the entropy is computationally efficient). The problem, however, is that the distribution is not flexible enough. How could one obtain the analytical formula of the joint PMF with copulas, when the marginals are $\mathsf{NBin}$?

Comment: You can get a joint PMF with copulas for discrete data - although I'm not going to lie: it's not as pretty as in the abs. continuous case. However there is research available. You can (for example) start with the paper: Geenens (2020): Copula modeling for discrete random vectors. Depend. Model. (8). (https://www.degruyter.com/journal/key/demo/8/1/html) (see Section 8) or just start with a search for "copula discrete margins". Of course there is now a lot of new information to absorb... but maybe you can get something useful out of it for your problem

Comment: I agree, there's a lot to parse, and perhaps the copula solution is not ideal for the discrete case, but thanks a lot for the reference! Another potential direction might be to derive the joint PMF from a probability generating function (PGF) - this was the approach taken by Dunn. However, it is not clear to me how the PGF can be specified in the first place. Are you able to shed some light on this? I would need to increase the flexibility of the original $\textsf{BNBin}$ distribution and make it more generic (by increasing the number of parameters, potentially).